# How to send an array of Int not a JSON in Alamofire parameters

Tags: swift, parameters, alamofire

my problem is how to send an array of `Int ([1,2,3,4])` in parameters in Alamofire. My array is not a JSON format just an array of Int, because the server expect this `([1,2,3,4])` without any keys.

In my code how I can send `"userInfos:[Int]"` in the function parameter in Alamofire parameters?

```swift
 func putPreferences(workId: String, userInfos:[Int] ) {

        let token = NSObject.getValueForKey(key: "userToken") as! String
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization" : token,
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
        ]

        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(userInfos)
        let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])) as? [String:AnyObject]
        print(json)
        let url = "URL"
        print(url)
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: json , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<501)

            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    if (response.response?.statusCode)! <= 300{
                        print(data)

                    }
                    else{
                        print(data)
                        print("error")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    // self.signupDelegtae?.signUpFailed()
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the Data that your array expects. There is many different types of integers

Comment: @LeoDabus i wanna send array of Int like this [1,3,65,22] , how to do this the parameters of Alamofire expect a [String:Any] but I wanna send just array of Int

Comment: You can use URLSession dataTask with URLRequest to send any kind of Data

Comment: yeah but actually I'm using Alamofire if that is possible with Alamofire?